# Function called once, but firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

The following is a snippet from a PhantomJS script. It tracks dynamic content on an AJAXd webpage. track() is called once, but for some reason page.open() is called 3 times

```
    function track(url){
        console.log('Tracking',url);
        var page = require('webpage').create();
        console.log('check2')
        if(page){
            console.log('check4');
            page.open(url, function (status) {
                console.log('check3');
                if (status !== 'success') {
                    console.log('Unable to load the address!');
                    setTimeout(function(){start();},1000);
                    setTimeout(function(){page.release();},5000);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('check');
                    var i = 0;
                    var last_winner = false;
                    var logged_once = false;
                    var interval = false;
                    if(!interval){
                        interval = setInterval(function(){
                            var scraping = scrape(page);
                            var date = new Date();
                            var time = date.getTime();
                            if(scraping){/*Bunch of console logs*/}
                            else{
                                console.log('Bidding ended');
                                clearInterval(interval);
                                setTimeout(function(){start();},1000);
                                setTimeout(function(){page.release();},5000);
                            }
                            scraping = false;
                       },1000);
                    };
                };
            });
        };
    };
```

Logs the following to the console:

```
Tracking http://www.google.com
check2
check4
check3
check
check3
check
check3
check
```

For some reason I can't figure out, page.open() is being called 3 times.

Comment: I'd try to figure out, what the page object really is: `console.log(page);`

Comment: try changing console.log('check3'); to console.log(status); and see what you get.  I have a feeling it loops through open() a few times while it's processing http status codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently PhantomJS calls page.open multiple times if there are redirects or iFrames being loaded on the page.

There are some suggestions of how to handle that on the PhantomJS bug tracker.

http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=353&q=open%20callback